# How to stop remote bash script with sshpass in case of any error

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, sshpass

i am using sshpass to run commands on a remote server as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@server -p PORT 'bash -s' << \EOF
Command1
Command2
sudo -i
set -e
Command3
Command4
Command5
exit
exit
EOF
```

And it runs okay, but if there is error on Command 3, it skips 4 and 5 and do the first `exit` and apply both commands 4 and 5 using the original user (**ubuntu**).

How to make the script totally stops if there is any error generated by any command?

Comment: My guess is that the problem does not come from sshpass/bash -s but your command 3.  It exits your current shell.

Comment: Even if it exists from current shell, why does it pass the 4 and 5 to the external shell?